# [__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance - source code and screenshot attached

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, unrecognized-selector

At GitHub I have [a simple iPhone app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/oauthMailru), which fetches user information (by using OAuth) from the social network Mail.ru:

[image: app screenshot]

It does fetch and print the information, but then crashes.

As an iOS programming newbie I'm confused by the output below (also please see [the full output at PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/euEjyf3g)):

```
2014-01-21 21:21:10.873 oauthMailru[8228:3307] -[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a97290
2014-01-21 21:21:10.875 oauthMailru[8228:3307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a97290'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01aa65e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018298b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b43903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a9690b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01a964ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   oauthMailru                         0x00003a62 __47-[ViewController fetchMailruWithToken:ForUser:]_block_invoke + 402
    6   Foundation                          0x01545695 __67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 151
    7   Foundation                          0x014a5945 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 88
    8   Foundation                          0x014fe829 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 671
    9   Foundation                          0x0147b558 -[NSOperation start] + 83
    10  Foundation                          0x01500af4 __NSOQSchedule_f + 62
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x021344b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02121018 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 202
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x021344b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02122eeb _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 287
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02123137 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x024c0dab _pthread_wqthread + 336
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x024c4cce start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Does anybody please know what's happening and how to read such crashes?

My source files: [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/9c6e64af454dbc43a6b5a04e06d3effae93571d1/oauthMailru/oauthMailru/ViewController.m), which displays `UIWebView` and then segues to [DetailViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthMailru/oauthMailru/DetailViewController.m)

Comment: Note that the error message is pretty explicit if you read it closely.  It says you have an array (`__NSArrayM` is the internal class name for an NSArray) and you're trying to do "keyed" (vs "indexed") operation on it.  The "traceback" tells you that the error occurred in your `fetchMailruWithToken:` method of `ViewController` (the first non-system method in the list), so look there for an `objectForKey` operation or some such.  Re-run with a breakpoint on that operation and dump the object at that point.  What you think is an NSDictionary will turn out to be an NSArray.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code thinks the JSON deserializes to an object (dictionary), but in fact it deserializes to an array containing one object.  Try this:

```
 NSMutableArray *topLevelArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
 NSDictionary *dict = topLevelArray[0];
```

If you want to check what you're getting, you can use `isKindOfClass:` like this:

```
id jso = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
if (jso == nil) {
    // Error.  You should probably have passed an NSError ** as the error
    // argument so you could log it.
} else if ([jso isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSArray *array = jso;
    // process array elements
} else if ([jso isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *dict = jso;
    // process dictionary elements
} else {
    // Shouldn't happen unless you use the NSJSONReadingAllowFragments flag.
}
```

Comment: It's in your debug output.  It says `dict=(`.  When you log an array, it's surrounded by parentheses.  When you log a dictionary, it's surrounded by curly braces.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. One last question please: in your suggested code you assign to an `NSMutableArray`, but what if the parsed JSON is not an array (for some reason), how to catch such "exceptions"?